# Find an equation of variation in which $y$ varies jointly as $t$ and $r$ and inversely as the square of $w$, and $y=2$ when $t=4, r=9,$ and $w=6$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratic-variation

> Find an equation of variation in which $y$ varies jointly as $t$ and $r$ and inversely as the square of $w$, and $y=2$ when $t=4, r=9,$ and $w=6$.

I can set this up as two separate equations, $y=ktr$, and $y=\dfrac k{w^2}$. Then I can:

- solve it as $k=\dfrac 1{18}$ for the first equation and $k=72$ for the second equation.
- Set the $y's $ equal to each other, which gives me $ktr=\dfrac k{w^2}$, which simplifies to $trw^2=1$, which is incorrect.

Both seem wrong; how do I solve this?

Comment: Both k are different how did you cancel

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Joint Proportionality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2753852/joint-proportionality)

Answer (score 0):

I would combine them together into a single equation, with a single constant $K$ to solve for:
$$
y = K \cdot \frac{tr}{w^2}
$$

Comment: How did you combine them like that?

Comment: Please respond...